# How to replace the % character with something else with the SET command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I know how to do simple string replacing with the SET command.

Example:

```
set /p a=
set a=%a:<=^<%
echo %a%
```

(This example will change the prompted variable to the same thing but with the < character to be ^< to be be properly echoed if needed to)

I want to do the same thing but with the % character but I can't get it to work.

Comment: This could be a [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), probably you can solve your real problem without replacing anything. You should describe your problem, not your assumed solution

Comment: I edited my question to be more properly explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "something=%%he%%llo%%"
ECHO %something%
ECHO ============
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "anotherthing=!something:%%=x!"
endlocal&SET "anotherthing=%anotherthing%"
ECHO %something%
ECHO %anotherthing%
GOTO :EOF
```

Like this, you mean?

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with your method, short of using doublequotes to protect from poison characters.

The main issue now, is in trying to see the content, because you'd be `Echo`ing poison characters. To see it actually in place I included two methods, a `Set` command to list all variables beginning with `a`, *(with a `findstr` thrown in to isolate only the one named `a`)*, and by using delayed expansion, which prevents the variable from being expanded when the command line is read/parsed. At the very bottom I included a method of showing it with the `Echo` command without using delayed expansion or doublequotes, as you can see to escape a caret, `^`, you'll need in this case to use two more carets

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "a="
Set /P "a="
Set "a=%a:<=^<%"
Echo(%a%
Pause

(Set a) 2> NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /L /I "a="
Pause

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Echo(!a!
EndLocal
Pause

Echo(%a:^<=^^^<%
Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

The full (known) rules for variable replacement can be found at [SO:
Percent Expansion Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970912/463115)

In short:
The search expression in a percent replacement expression can not start with a percent.
The search expression in a delayed replacement expression can not start with a exclamation mark.

But you can replace percent signs with delayed expression

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p var=
set "var=!var:%%=REPLACE!"
echo(!var!
```

The percent sign itself has to be doubled here, because it collapse to a single percent in phase2 (percent expansion)